# Dynamically use different database based on previous lookup with AbstractRoutingDataSource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

We will face high data volume on our mariadb databases. To overcome problems with backups and ddl operations, we had the idea to store the data into multiple databases. Basically we will have a database with short term data (e.g. last 30 days, named short_term) and another one with the rest of the data (named long_term). Obviously the data needs to be moved from short_term to long_term but that should be achievable.

The problem I'm currently facing on a prototype is that I can connect to short_term but am not able to switch to long_term if for example want to query both of them (e.g. get() where I can't find it in the short_term database).

I have set it up like this (both work independently but not with switch database context):

HistoryAwareRoutingSource:

```
public class HistoryAwareRoutingSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return ThreadLocalStorage.getDatabaseType();
    }
}
```

ThreadLocalStorage

```
public class ThreadLocalStorage {

    private static ThreadLocal<String> databaseType = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setDatabaseType(String databaseTypeName) {
        databaseType.set(databaseTypeName);
    }

    public static String getDatabaseType() {
        return databaseType.get();
    }
}
```

DatasourceConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String db1Url;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String db1Username;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String db1Password;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String db1DriverClassName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.connectionProperties}")
    private String db1ConnectionProps;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.sqlScriptEncoding}")
    private String db1Encoding;

    @Value("${spring.datasource2.url}")
    private String db2Url;

    @Value("${spring.datasource2.username}")
    private String db2Username;

    @Value("${spring.datasource2.password}")
    private String db2Password;

    @Value("${spring.datasource2.driver-class-name}")
    private String db2DriverClassName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource2.connectionProperties}")
    private String db2ConnectionProps;

    @Value("${spring.datasource2.sqlScriptEncoding}")
    private String db2Encoding;


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HistoryAwareRoutingSource historyAwareRoutingSource = new HistoryAwareRoutingSource();
        Map<Object, Object> dataSourceMap = new HashMap<>();
        dataSourceMap.put("PRIMARY", dataSource1());
        dataSourceMap.put("SECONDARY", dataSource2());
        historyAwareRoutingSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSource1());
        historyAwareRoutingSource.setTargetDataSources(dataSourceMap);

        historyAwareRoutingSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        return historyAwareRoutingSource;
    }

    private DataSource dataSource1() {
        HikariDataSource primary = new HikariDataSource();
        primary.setInitializationFailTimeout(0);
        primary.setMaximumPoolSize(5);
        primary.setDriverClassName(db1DriverClassName);
        primary.setJdbcUrl(db1Url);
        primary.setUsername(db1Username);
        primary.setPassword(db1Password);

        primary.addDataSourceProperty("connectionProperties", db1ConnectionProps);
        primary.addDataSourceProperty("sqlScriptEncoding", db1Encoding);
        return primary;
    }

    private DataSource dataSource2() {
        HikariDataSource secondary = new HikariDataSource();
        secondary.setInitializationFailTimeout(0);
        secondary.setMaximumPoolSize(5);
        secondary.setDriverClassName(db2DriverClassName);
        secondary.setJdbcUrl(db2Url);
        secondary.setUsername(db2Username);
        secondary.setPassword(db2Password);

        secondary.addDataSourceProperty("connectionProperties", db2ConnectionProps);
        secondary.addDataSourceProperty("sqlScriptEncoding", db2Encoding);
         return secondary;
    }
}
```

Then I have a RestController class like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/story")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MultiDBController {

    @Autowired
    private StoryService storyService;

    @GetMapping("/create")
    @UsePrimaryStorage
    public ResponseEntity<StoryDTO> createEntity() {
        setPrimaryDB();

        return ResponseEntity.ok(storyService.createOne());
    }


    private void setPrimaryDB() {
        // TODO destroy the current db connection or hand it back to the pool so the next time a connect is taken it is the PRIMARY Datasource?
        ThreadLocalStorage.setDatabaseType("PRIMARY");
    }


    private void setSecondaryDB() {
        // TODO destroy the current db connection or hand it back to the pool so the next time a connect is taken it is the PRIMARY Datasource?

        ThreadLocalStorage.setDatabaseType("SECONDARY");
    }

    @GetMapping("/{storyId}")
    public ResponseEntity<StoryDTO> get(@PathVariable UUID storyId) {
        // try to find in primary db
        setPrimaryDB();
        Optional<StoryDTO> storyOptional = storyService.findOne(storyId);

        if (!storyOptional.isPresent()) {
            setSecondaryDB();
            Optional<StoryDTO> storyOptionalSecondary = storyService.findOne(storyId);
            if(storyOptionalSecondary.isPresent()) {
                return ResponseEntity.ok(storyOptionalSecondary.get());
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
            }
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(storyOptional.get());
    }
}
```

So the question is, how do I implement the TODO's

Comment: Shouldn't you implement this on the DB level instead of the software level? You probably want to look into database sharding and how to implement that for your database. You shouldn't put this burden on the application-developer but rather in the infrastructure, set it up once and then it is transparent for the application.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible. Not with views (no writes), not with partitions (long lasting ddl commands), etc. The only option would be to move towards a document store but there will also be the issue with restoring large backups

Comment: Why wouldn't that be possible? Isn't that just the whole point of sharding your database...

Comment: I guess I was not precise enough. We're actually using mariadb (fixed above) and there it would be possible to use maxscale (product) or proxysql to achieve something similar. But let's assue I don't want that for different reasons or just as a prototype solution...

Comment: Disable the open entity manager in view functionality to be able to switch (it now obtains a database connection prior to your code being hit). This will give you probably different errors with lazy loading but that is what you have to work with. Also your code shouldn't use if statements use the `orElse` instead of ifs. That way you can nicely chain your code. Nonetheless you really shouldn't be placing this burden into your application, at one point it will start to bite you (updates going wrong, inserting into wrong db etc. etc.).